# Moving or Copying files from one NAS to another while maintaining Timestamps

Tags: filesystems, nas, btrfs, timestamp

Some of our designers want to move some of their old files from our active Synology unit to an archive Synology unit using their windows machines. But it is imperative all the timestamps (created, modified, accessed) remain the same. Both units are Btrfs file system and the client connects via SMB2.
Thanks,
Al